# Regex: find the index of match

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I want to find all `image:` in a .yaml file, and replace the first match with `image:1.jpg`, and second `image:2.jpg`, etc. To do this, I think I need to find out the indexes of regex matches and replace them accordingly. Is this possible? Can I do it in Atom? Besides, is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. First, install increment-selection: https://atom.io/packages/increment-selection
2. Then, enable regex search and do a search for "image:.*" and replace with "image:aaaaa.jpg"
3. Then do a find all on "aaaaa" and hit ctrl-shift-i to replace that with incrementing numbers. You should end up with `image:1.jpg`, `image:2.jpg` and so on.